# What is $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup X_n$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \inf X_n$ almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have that ${X_n}$ is an independent sequence. Where

$P[X_n=n]=\frac{1}{n}$,

$P[X_n=0]=1-\frac{1}{n}$.

So, ${X_n}$ converge almost surely?

And what is $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup X_n$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \inf X_n$ almost surely?

I know that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {P[{X_n} = n} ] = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}}  = \infty $ (harmonic serie). Since ${X_n}$ is independent, by "Borel-Canteli 0_1" we have

$P\{ [{X_n} = n]  i.o.\}  = 1$.

For now, I don't know if I'm in the right way.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_n = n \, \text{i.o.})=1$ implies that $X_n$ converges almost surely? What makes you think so?

Comment: I didn't ask a Yes-/No-Question, did I? Actually the intention of my comment was to make you think once more about your claim that $X_n$ converges almost surely. (It doesn't converge!)

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood. And now I'm more confused how to show this. Do you have any hint?

Comment: I think you could see how limsup and liminf behave from this result that you got by Borel Canteli.

Comment: Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_n \in \{0,n\}$ for all $n$. Let's assume that there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0$ and also infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=n$. What can you tell me about $\liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Comment: Alright, I think I got it.  So, $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup n_n=\infty$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sup n_n=0$. And ${X_n}$ does not converge?